# How to off auto escaping (backslash) double quote when i log with AccessLogValve of Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat8, access-log

I have to make logs using AccessLogValve of tomcat8.
The logs include double quote.

Tomcat server.xml below

```xml
...
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="mypage.com">
    <Host name="mypage.com" appBase="/home1/irteam/mypage"
            workDir="work" unpackWARs="false" deployOnStartup="false"
            autoDeploy="false">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               directory="/home1/irteam/apps/tomcat/logs"
               prefix="accesslog."
               resolveHosts="false"
               fileDateFormat="yyMMdd"
               pattern="%{timestamp}r, &quot;data&quot;:%{request_data}r"
               requestAttributesEnabled="true"
               encoding="utf-8" />

...
```

log example below

```
20230224160000, "data":[{\"code\":\"retry_num\",\"count\":1},{\"code\":\"visit_num\",\"count\":1}]
```

Although i passed data without escape symble, AccessLogValve make automatically escape symbol (backslash) for double quote in passed data (request, header, session ...).
I found documentation explained to adding function of auto escaping for double quote.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html

I have to make log with double quote. Can I off auto escaping for double quote?

I tried below about passed data (request, header, session...) in java code

- replace("\\", "")
- replace(""", """)
- Using replace function in java code is meaningless, because making escape symbol is occured in AccessLogValve of Tomcat.

Comment: Escaping input data on logs might be done for security concerns,

Comment: @LMC you mean I can't remove escaping symbol anyway?

Comment: May be you shouldn't alter logging and think of log processing instead.